# Can't boot Ubuntu 16.04 from usb. Restart loop. (dual boot with windows 7)

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, uefi, lenovo

I previously had Ubuntu 14.04 installed alongside windows 7, but I just freed my Ubuntu partition in hopes of installing 16.04. My boot order is correct, and on startup the GRUB menu appears asking me if I want to install ubuntu. The problem is that when I select "install ubuntu" my computer simply restarts. Some notes on my settings:

```
UEFI BIOS VERSION: 2.16
UEFI Secure Boot:  Off
```

I have tried UEFI and Legacy boot but the problem persists. I really have no idea what is going on. I have tried both Universal USB Installer and Rufus to install to usb. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Which iso file did you download? What computer is it (brand name and model)? -- Without knowing more details I would recommend **ubuntu-16.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso** that you find via http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/xenial/ ; check with `md5sum` that the download was correct and install it with Rufus (an extracting tool) or Win32 Disk Imager (a cloning tool). -- 'Try Ubuntu', http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2230389

Comment: I am using the 64bit iso file found [here](http://releases.ubuntu.com/16.04/). I am using a lenovo t430u. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: The `ubuntu-16.04.3-desktop-amd64.iso  ` file comes with the zesty kernel (the same linux kernel as in 17.04). There *may be* problems with the drivers belonging to it to cooperate with the hardware in your computer. The first point release 16.04.1 LTS is well polished and debugged, it comes with the xenial kernel and it is the version with longest remaining support until end of life among the current versions of Ubuntu. -- There could also be problems because of bad download or bad creation of the USB boot drive.

Comment: It seems like the error does not happen when using **ubuntu-17.04-desktop-amd64.iso** for some reason. Any ideas on why this could be the case? I did not change any bios settings.

Comment: No I don't know. 17.04 uses the same kernel series as 16.04.3, but a lot of program packages are different (at least different versions). I suggest that you simply select a version that works (but please realize that 17.04 has a short lifetime, only 9 months from the release, until January 2018). You might test if the next version 'Artful' will work. It will be released as 17.10 soon (in October), and you can get a daily iso file via this link, http://iso.qa.ubuntu.com/qatracker/milestones/376/builds

Comment: Strange. Well I've spent way more time on this than I wanted so I'm gonna stick with 17.04 for now. I was planning on upgrading my computer in a few months anyways. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You are welcome :-) Good luck with 17.04 and if you keep the computer, please remember to change to a current version of Ubuntu, in January, when 17.04 reaches end of life. The specs of Lenovo t430u indicate, that it can live a long life with Ubuntu and later on with light-weight Ubuntu community flavours, so if you get a new computer, you might keep this Lenovo as a dedicated linux computer.

Comment: I've got one computer that *sometimes* reboots in the way you describe. It can take several attempts before it boots, after which point everything is fine. (The computer is my MythTV backend, so it can stay up for months at a time.) Some kernels seem more reliable than others -- or maybe that's just chance at work. This computer uses an MSI A88X-G43 motherboard, FWIW. This would be infuriating on a computer that I rebooted frequently, but because it stays up for extended periods, I just put up with it.